# How to send a value one view to another view in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I' developing cross-platform mobile application using Sencha Touch and I followed MVC pattern in MVC. Here I have to send a value from one view to another view. can you please sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this scenario:

SenderView :

```
initComponent: function () {

var foo = 'bar';
// call to parent initComponent....

this.query('#buttonID')[0].on({
  scope: this,
  tap: function (ct) {
    Ext.dispatch({
      controller: 'MyController',
      action: 'myaction',
      foo: foo
    })
  }
})
}
```

MyController:

```
myaction : function (options) {
  var foo = options.foo;
  this.render ({
    xtype: 'myview',
    foo: foo
  })

}
```

MyView:

```
initComponent: function () {
  var config = this.initialConfig,
    // hopla! foo is transmitted from SenderView to the MyView
    foo = config.foo;
    ...
   console.log(foo) ; // bar
}
```

the code not really tested, but idea is clear, I hope :)

Oleg